# typescript array is empty after using .push method

Tags: typescript

I am trying to populate an array `zvols` which contains name of the path of a list of zvols. The problem is I am getting an empty array after successful get call,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { EntityUtils } from '../pages/common/entity/utils'
import { RestService, WebSocketService } from '../services/';


@Injectable()
export class VmService {
    protected volume_resource_name: string = 'storage/volume'

    constructor(protected rest: RestService){
    };

getStorageVolumes() {
    let zvols: Array<any> = [];
    this.rest.get(this.volume_resource_name , {}).subscribe((res) => {
        let data = new EntityUtils().flattenData(res.data);
        for (let zvol_obj of data){
            if (zvol_obj.type === 'zvol') {
                zvols.push(zvol_obj.path);
            }
        }
        console.log("BEFORE:" + zvols);
    });
     console.log("AFTER:" + zvols);
    return zvols;
}
}
```

I can see that console prints

```
AFTER:
main.bundle.js:744 Unknown message:  Object {msg: "ready", subs: Array(1)}
vm.service.ts:26 BEFORE:tank-a/ds-a/zvol-a,tank-b/ds-b/zvol-b
```

I am confused about this behavior. :(

Comment: What you see in the console is that AFTER is printer before BEFORE. It means that  your 'BEFORE'  `console.log()` is actually called after `return zvols`, in the callback function. You can't return the result of async operation like that.

Comment: ok, please tell me how can I return the result of asnyc call ?

Comment: You can't. You have to use it in the callback. How - it depends on what exactly you want to do with it. You can return the result of `get()` from `getStorageVolumes()`, then the code that calls it should do a `subscribe()` and use the result in the callback  it provides to `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
this.rest.get(this.volume_resource_name , {}).subscribe((res) => {
    let data = new EntityUtils().flattenData(res.data);
    for (let zvol_obj of data){
        if (zvol_obj.type === 'zvol') {
            zvols.push(zvol_obj.path);
        }
    }
    console.log("BEFORE:" + zvols);
});
 console.log("AFTER:" + zvols);
```

`AFTER` executes *before* the `BEFORE` line. This is the nature of async programming.

## Learning Async programming

Use a debugger and step through the code to see how it works.

Comment: So I put in debugger right before `this.rest.get(this.volume_resource_name , {}).subscribe((res) => {` and I saw that it directly went to `return zvols;` what am I missing here ?